# dockerfile cannot remove Device or resource busy

Tags: docker

I'm trying to do:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

COPY ./db /var/lib/mysql
```

And I get the error :

> rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mysql': Device or resource busy

I don't really need to `rm` the folder, I just want to overwrite, but for some reason the dockerfile doesn't overwrite, the `COPY` instruction just seems to fail silently.

Not sure if there's caching going on or something but I use `--no-cache`, (this isn't the first time I built the image but files have changed).

How I can debug?

Comment: what is your target ? use some other base images if you want to install your own mysql service

Comment: You need to understand that what you are doing is not how Docker images work. Even should you succeed, the old `/var/lib/mysql` *is still there* in the base image layer. Even though it won't be accessible, it will still add to the final image size. As stated above, if you need to roll your own mysql container, then do just that. The stock mysql dockerfiles are available in the github repo, so you could modify one of these.
What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`mysql` Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/Dockerfile#L67) declares

```
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
```

That directly leads to the error you're seeing.  (At a low level Docker causes the volume to be mounted on that directory, as in the normal Linux `mount` command/function, so you can't delete the mount point.)

It also has the consequence that derived images can't make any changes in that directory tree, so your fundamental approach here won't work.  If you already have a data tree that can work here, you can use the `docker run -v` option to mount it into a container

```
docker run -v $PWD/db:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7
```

If you just have a dump file, you can mount or copy it into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`; this mechanism is described on the [Docker Hub `mysql` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) (under "Initializing a fresh instance").

Comment: Thanks I ended up forking the official docker files and commenting out the volume. there's no way to remove a volume from a parent image

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command to fix this issue.

- remove all stopped container

```
$ docker system prune
```

my docker version is Docker version 20.10.2

Comment: `sudo docker system prune` pruned, but still did not allow the use of `sudo rm -rv /var/lib/docker/aufs/` on `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`.

Comment: Maybe it still has some processes is running, find the running process and kill it